# npm - подгрузка зависимостей при установке модуля

Tags: npm, node.js

В общем проблема такая: знакомый опубликовал npm модуль, но он ставится без зависимостей.

Сразу после установки срабатывает gulp build, но самого gulpa в локальном модуле (соответственно) нет.

Хотелось бы чтобы зависимости подтягивались при установке модуля. Как это реализовать?

Пробовал поиграться с директивами preinstall/postinstall - но при таком подходе установка попросту зацикливается, я думаю из-за жизненного цикла самого npm.

***package.json***

```js
{
  "name": "yopta",
  "version": "0.3.0-patch1",
  "description": "YoptaScript - язык программирования для гопников и реальных пацанов.",
  "main": "./src/core.js",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "gulp build",
    "build": "gulp build",
    "dist": "gulp build",
    "start": "gulp watch",
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "bin": {
    "yopta": "./src/cli.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/samgozman/YoptaScript"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "transpiler",
    "yopta",
    "language",
    "yoptascript"
  ],
  "author": "samgozman",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/samgozman/YoptaScript/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://yopta.space/",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "browserify": "^13.1.1",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-add": "0.0.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.9.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суть проблемы была в том, что я не до конца понимал как работает npm. Дело в том, что у меня зависимости были объявлены в директиве devDependencies, а надо чтобы были в dependencies. Если у кого будут похожие проблемы, надеюсь, это поможет. npm при установке модуля выкачивает зависимости рекурсивно.